# iPhone app size greater than 600MB

Tags: iphone, ipad, size

I am building an iPad application for playing the videos. I am planing to include the videos and other related stuff into the app itself. So the app size would be approximately 600MB+.
I have found that Apple allows maximum app size of 2GB. Also for the app with the size more than 20MB, WIFI is required.

Please guide me whether I can bundle all the video files in the app itself?or any other better solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Would people be willing to download a 600 MB app? And another when an update comes? Maybe you should be clear in why you want the videos to be inside the app; then we can guide you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please guide me whether I can bundle
>   all the video files in the app itself?

Yes, you can.

> or any other better solution for this?

Yes, there most certainly is.

Any user who accidentally buys your app and is faced with a 600MB download is not going to be a happy camper. You've already pissed off your user and they haven't even launched your app for the first time!

Find a good CDN and make your videos available over HTTP. YouTube might even work. Then stream them to your clients instead.

I'm not sure what kind of app requires 600MB of videos, but my gut tells me the basic design has a fundamental flaw.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one more thing.

Keep some videos in app and keep some online, use streaming through video URLs. Bundle some of your videos in app such that app size does not increase and cache the streamed videos when any user downloads the app.

But more the memory app uses, more chances of crash are there. So be careful with your implementation.